# Stuck at one node's exercise

Tags: node.js

Hi guys i have started to learn node i am learning from **learnyounode** now i am stuck since yesterday at exercise 6 for module 
after trying by my code i couldn't solve that so after searching i got a url sample all exercises of learnyounode

**https://github.com/proustibat/Node.js-Learnyounode-exercises**

even i copied 6th exercise's code to work but not working other all code's are working though.

### main test.js

```js
var mymodulelist = require('./mymodule.js');

var dirWanted = ".";
if (process.argv[2] !== undefined) {
 dirWanted = process.argv[2];
}

var extWanted = "*";
if (process.argv[3] !== undefined) {
 extWanted = process.argv[3];
}

mymodulelist(dirWanted, extWanted, function(err, list) {
 if (err) {
  return console.log(err);
 }
 list.forEach(function(file) {
  console.log(file);
 })
});
```

### Module mymodule.js

```js
var fs = require('fs')

module.exports = function(dirname, filter, callback) {
 var regex = new RegExp('\\.' + filter + '$')    

 var filelist = new Array();
 var i = 0

 fs.readdir(dirname, function (err, list) {

  if (err) {
   return callback(err);
  }
  else {
   list.forEach(function (file) {
    if (regex.test(file))
     filelist[i] = file;
     i += 1;
   })
  }
  return callback(null, filelist);
 });

};
```

here after **learnyounode verify test.js** i got this error

- √ Submission results match expected
- √ Additional module file exports a single function
- √ Additional module file exports a function that takes 3 arguments
- √ Additional module file handles errors properly
- √ Additional module file handles callback argument
- √ Additional module file returned two arguments on the callback
  function
- √ Additional module file returned correct number of elements as the
  second argument of the  callback
- √ Additional module file correctly handles '.'-prefixed extension ?
  Your additional module file [mymodule.js] did not return an Array
  with the correct numbe
- r of elements as the second argument of the callback
- ## FAIL
- Your solution to MAKE IT MODULAR didn't pass. Try again!

even i have googled out and somewhere also suggested to upgrade learyounode update even i also does that but still i am stopped at this point

Any suggestions or Solution for this..???

Thank you in advance guys...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're verifying the correct file.
With the code above it passes for me:
[image]

Comment: yup i am sure  i am verifying the **test.js** and it's correct file need to verify right..?

Comment: yes you have to verify test.js and excercise 6 needs to be the last exercise you've selected

Comment: what needy is all that i am doing actually for that i have also provided the console's error that all sub-tests it passes but at the end where need to return list of array in callback that some how not getting though correct as i know

Comment: everything seems fine with your code. In fact I've used the code you've provided and the tests passed.

Comment: is it like installer issue with node or learnyounode packages?